# tryin to make function that hide divs but cheking if they have a class before it do

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a solution since now some day, but can't find out the way to do that. I have one function on a button that hide every div that doesn't have the class polyester.

Then I have another button want to hide everything else except but I don't want to hide what's displayed already ( polyester in this case ), what does the active class.

```
    let polyval = document.getElementById('poly').getAttribute('value'); 
    let lightval = document.getElementById('light').getAttribute('value');

    function showpoly(e){


        const poly = document.getElementById('poly');


        const nopoly = document.querySelectorAll("div.webbing:not(.polyester)");
        const len = nopoly.length;






        if(polyval  < 1) {
            polyval++;

            for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
                nopoly[i].classList.add('active');

            }



        }else    {

            polyval--;
            for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
            nopoly[i].classList.remove('active');

                }


            }

        }


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>What webbing will you buy next ?</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


    <h1>WHAT WEBBING WILL I BUY NEXT ?</h1>

    <div class="container">


        <div class="row">

            <div class="col s12">
                    <a onclick="showpoly();" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">Polyester</a>
                <a onclick="showlight();" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">Light</a>
            </div>

        </div>    

        <div class="row">

            <div value="0" class="col s2 webbing polyamid">
                Polyamid
            </div>
            <div value="0" id="poly" class="col s2 webbing polyester">
                Polyester
            </div>
            <div value="0" class="col s2 webbing nylon">
                Nylon
            </div>
            <div value="0" class="col s2 webbing tubular">
                Tubular
            </div>
            <div value="0" class="col s2 webbing heavy">
                Heavy
            </div>
            <div value="0" id="light" class="col s2 webbing light">
                Light
            </div>





            <div value="0" class="col s2 webbing polyamid">
                Polyamid
            </div>
            <div  value="0" id="poly" class="col s2 webbing polyester">
                Polyester
            </div>
            <div value="0" class="col s2 webbing nylon">
                Nylon
            </div>
            <div value="0" class="col s2 webbing tubular">
                Tubular
            </div>
            <div value="0" class="col s2 webbing heavy">
                Heavy
            </div>
            <div value="0" id="light" class="col s2 webbing light">
                Light
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want to hide everything that doesn't have the active class?

Comment: sorry not really good in english ^^. I want to hide everything that do not have light class, but it has to check first if some div have the class active so it hide everything else except light and others div that have class active. s that clear ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery's hasClass(); function to check whether the Element has the class or not.

It would be something like this in your case

```
    if ($(element).hasClass('polyester')) {
   // Do Nothing! 
}
else {
//Hide That Div! 
}
```

I haven't used the not(!) with the condition just to make it simple for you, otherwise you can use the ! not condition to flip the condition so it will be

```
 if (!$(element).hasClass('polyester')) {
// Hide code
}
```

Please replace the (element) with your desired element. and use this on the Click event of the button....

Sorry can't create the exact code for you, due to shortage of time! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla js:

```
function hideWithoutClass(nodeList, className) {
    nodeList.forEach( v => {
        if (!v.classList.contains(className)) v.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    })
}
```